# Should I use numpy's Random Generator?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large Python code that I've been maintaining/updating/expanding since ~2014. Recently I came across `numpy`'s [Random Number Generator Policy](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html) (2018-05) and now I'm a bit confused.

I'm not sure what changed, and if I should upgrade my code accordingly to use the new [Random Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html). For example, the [Random sampling](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/index.html) docs say:

```
# Do this
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
vals = rng.standard_normal(10)
more_vals = rng.standard_normal(10)

# instead of this
from numpy import random
vals = random.standard_normal(10)
more_vals = random.standard_normal(10)
```

All my code depends on the (old?) syntax shown in the second block (i.e., I don't use `default_rng` but simple calls to `np.random.seed()`, `np.random.uniform()`, `np.random.normal()`, etc), and I don't know why I should use the first block instead of the second block.

Could someone shed some light over this please?

Comment: At this stage, it's a matter of choice. The default implementation works fine for many applications. Without knowing more specifics about your use cases, it's impossible to tell. Based on the fact that you've been doing this successfully since 2014, you're fine as is.

Comment: If your code works, I wouldn't worry about it much.

Comment: Read through the [Implementation](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html#implementation) section carefully. Do you care that the exact bit-stream of the generator *may* change at some point in the future? If not, completely ignore this.

Comment: I'll break it down in an answer if you update the question to indicate what exactly your requirements are. Without knowing that, I can't tell if you'll care.

Comment: My code does not rely too heavily on the random generation process. It mainly uses a few calls to `np.random.seed()` here and there for reproducibility across runs, and not much more.

Comment: In that case you should switch. Going forward, reproducibility of the default functions between versions is no longer guaranteed. Reproducibility is only guaranteed for a specific implementation of a generator

Answer (score -1):

1.In python2(old code) default_rng is not available.

2.In python3(new code) both first and second blocks you mentioned will runs without an error and executed.

3.In future they may drop the random.standard_normal from coming versions of python,that's why they mentioned to use of default_rng instead of random.standard_normal

Comment: The issue is not that the functions are not going to be there (they will). The issue is that they may not produce the same numbers for a given seed.